# How to align Bootstrap 4 navbar items to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align the text of the navbar items lowerin bootstrap 4. My idea was to align them to the bottom of the ul and then position the ul but I seem to fail to do both. The goal is to have the text (approximately) at the same height of the brand like this:

[image]

I have found some questions but most of them are for bootstrap 3 or don't work for some reason I don't understand.

This is example html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 800; font-style: italic; font-size:xx-large;">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" >
                <p style="vertical-align:bottom;" >Test</p>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item<?php addActiveClass('/index.php'); ?>">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Test</a>
            </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><img src="" id="profileImage" height="40" width="40" style="margin-right: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I use [this bootstrap theme](https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.css) and example css:

```
.navbar
{
    padding:0rem 0.75rem;
}
.navbar-brand
{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

  .navbar-nav > li
    {
        line-height: 36px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: red;
    }

  .navbar-nav > li > a 
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: red;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > p 
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: yellow;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

A complete example is available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/d6n5z3gb/8/

Comment: You could use `position: relative;` and `top: 10px` on the p (or a) elements. I would suggest changing the markup a bit, though, so you can get what you want easier. And `p` doesn't seem like a good element to use in the `nav`.  `span` might be better in my opinion.

Comment: The p is just because I got completely lost, it's not there in the actual code. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **`align-items-end`** to the `navbar-nav` to align the items to the bottom...

```
<ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item" >
    </li>
</ul>
```

And, remove the custom `line-height`...

```
.navbar-nav > li > a 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Update on Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/usR58ejrtg